# C# Order List based on average of nested list value with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm wondering if it is possible to use a lambda expression to order a list of items based on the average value of a nested list of items.

In project terms, I have a list of products that each can have many reviews. I want to order the list of the products based on the average rating from each product's list of reviews.

I have this:

```
products = category.Products.OrderBy(i => i.Reviews.Average(x => x.Rating));
```

This builds without a problem but when I run it, it returns an error that says

> *Sequence contains no elements*

Is it possible to do this with a lambda expression?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `i.Reviews` has 0 elements?

Comment: If there are zero reviews, what's the average?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enumerable.Average` throws the `InvalidOperationException` because the sequence contains no elements since a product has no `Reviews`.

You could use [`Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty(customValue)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx):

```
products = category.Products
    .OrderBy(i => i.Reviews.Select(r => r.Rating).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average());
```

Maybe you want to exclude these products from the result:

```
products = category.Products
    .Where(p => p.Reviews.Any())
    .OrderBy(p => p.Reviews.Average(r => r.Rating));
```

Comment: This is what I needed, only I needed `OrderByDescending` instead. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

One of your products probably has no reviews. You should decide what rating to give it, let's say 99 because you want it to appear at the end, so:

```
category.Products.OrderBy(p=>p.Reviews.Count > 0 ?
                          p.Reviews.Average(r=>r.Rating) : 99);
```

Comment: Use `Any` instead of `Count()`. Otherwise the whole sequence must be enumerated and evaluated to get the `Count` in case `Reviews` is not a `ICollection` but `IEnumerable`.